# Ayuda con formatos en datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms, datagrid

estoy tratando de realizar un desplegable en un datagridview. ya casi lo termino. pero tengo unas cosas que no se como solucionar, por ejemplo en mi datagridview, tengo contadores en la franja gris, esta cuenta la cantidad de productos que hay en cada agrupación, si no ven. se llama la columna inventario. pero dentro de estas tengo un valor de 0 que quisiera ocultar si el valor es 0, dejarlo en blanco, pero no se como realizaro. claro igual para la columna Cant_Copeo y Cant_Avierto dejarlos en blanco y el valor acumulado o contado se visible.
Esta la imagen del datagridview desplegadas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta cerradas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el codigo estoy uniendo 2 data tables, uno donde me agrupa los valores y otra donde contienen los registros puros.

```
 void CargarConDatatable() {
            DataTable table = new DataTable("Customers");

            table.Columns.Add("Accion", typeof(String));
            table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
            //workCol.AllowDBNull = false;
            //workCol.Unique = false;

            table.Columns.Add("Producto", typeof(String));
            table.Columns.Add("Inventario", typeof(Int32));
            table.Columns.Add("Copeo", typeof(bool));
            table.Columns.Add("Cant_Copeo", typeof(Int32));
            table.Columns.Add("Abierto", typeof(bool));
            table.Columns.Add("Cant_Abierto", typeof(Int32));
            //                ID Producto Inventrio     Copeo    Cant_Copeo   Abierto   Cant_Abierto
            table.Rows.Add("", 1, "Cola",    0,           1,         0,       1,            0);
            table.Rows.Add("", 1, "Cola",    0,           1,         0,       1,            0);
            table.Rows.Add("", 1, "Cola",    0,           1,         0,       0,            0);
            table.Rows.Add("", 1, "Cola",    0,           1,         0,       1,            0);

            table.Rows.Add("", 2, "Agua",    0,           1,         0,       1,            0);
            table.Rows.Add("", 2, "Agua",    0,           1,         0,       1,            0);
            table.Rows.Add("", 2, "Agua",    0,           1,         0,       1,            0);
            table.Rows.Add("", 2, "Agua",    0,           1,         0,       1,            0);

            table.Rows.Add("", 3, "Jugo",    0,           0,         0,       0,            0);
            table.Rows.Add("", 3, "Jugo",    0,           0,         0,       0,            0);
            table.Rows.Add("", 3, "Jugo",    0,           0,         0,       1,            0);

            var t = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
            group row by row.Field<Int32>("ID") into sales
            orderby sales.Key
            select new
            {
                Accion = "+",
                ID = sales.Key,
                Producto = sales.FirstOrDefault().Field<String>("Producto"),
                Inventario = sales.Count(),
                Cant_Copeo = sales.Count(x => x.Field<bool>("Copeo") == true),
                Cant_Abierto = sales.Count(x => x.Field<bool>("Abierto") == true)
            };

            DataTable dt = Utilitied.ToDataTable(t.ToList());

            var union = table.AsEnumerable().Union(dt.AsEnumerable()).OrderBy(d => d.Field<Int32>("ID"));

            table.Merge(dt);

            DataView dv = table.DefaultView;
            dv.Sort = "ID ASC";
            table = dv.ToTable();

            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = table; // t.ToList() ;

            this.dataGridView1.Columns["Cant_Copeo"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
            this.dataGridView1.Columns["Cant_Abierto"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d";

            this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode =  DataGridViewTriState.True;

            this.dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Coral;
            this.dataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;
            this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.DarkSalmon;
            this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
            //this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
}
```

// el codigo donde se ocultan los rows

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Completo");

            for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; col++)
                {
                   if (dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value != null  && dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.Equals(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.Equals("+"))
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Style.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                            dataGridView1.Rows[row].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                            //var cell = dataGridView1[0, row] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                            //cell.Style.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;

                        }
                    }

                }
                if (!dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value.Equals("+"))
                {
                    this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Visible = false;

                    var cell = dataGridView1[0, row] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();

                    cell.ReadOnly = true;
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control);
                }
            }

        }
```

y donde se realiza "el despliegue"

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Accion" && dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.Equals("+"))
            {
                    int index = e.RowIndex;
                    String ID = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

                    for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; row++)
                    {
                        String Valor = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

                        if (!this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Visible && ID.Equals(Valor))
                        {
                            this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Visible = true;
                        }
                        else if (this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Visible && ID.Equals(Valor) && index != row && dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor != Color.LightGray)
                        {
                            this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                            this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Visible = false;
                        }

                    }

            }

        }
```

Gracias..

Comment: que es lo que queres ocultar? porque no queda claro si es la columna o solo cambiar el valor a nada

Comment: cambiar el valor a blanco, es decir lo que esta dentro de la agrupacion/u oculto con valor a 0 cambiarlos a blanco, pero sin afectar el valor de la franja gris

Comment: Pero si los datos los estas pasando vos, porque solamente no pasas un blanco?

Comment: esta es una prueba que estoy haciendo, al final de cuentas voy a recibir un datatable de un StorageProcedure cuyos valores sean 0 y no "espacios en blanco",

Comment: AHHH perfecto.. faltaba esa aclaración ;) o sea que no podes modificar los datos.. hay que tocar la grilla.. listo.. genial.. veamos si alguien puede trabajar con eso...

Comment: se me ocurre que cuando te llegan los datos, si no puedes modificar ese datatable, los copies a otro datatable, y en ese datatable cambies los 0 por "" y uses ese datatable como source.

Comment: Debajo de la línea dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Style.BackColor = Color.Gray;  pon esto if (dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value == "0")
                dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value = ""; Esto cambiaría solo la columna inventario, tendrías que hacerlo por cada columna que quieras cambiar 0 por ""